# Python: re.sub gives different output when unicode character is fetched from a string variable containing data from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

The following works:

```
import re
text = "I\u2019m happy"
text_p = text
text_p = re.sub("[\u2019]","'",text_p)
print(text_p)
```

Output: I'm happy

This doesn't work:

```
training_data = pd.read_csv('train.txt')

import re
text = training_data['tweet_text'][0] # Assume that this returns a string "I\u2019m happy"
text_p = text
text_p = re.sub("[\u2019]","'",text_p)
print(text_p)
```

Output: I\u2019m happy

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code and got `I'm happy` returned from both the string and the list item when passing each into `re.sub(...)` as outlined in your question.

If you're just looking to parse (decode) the unicode characters you probably don't need to be using `re`. Something like the below could be used to parse the unicode characters without having to run `re` to check each possibility.

```py
text = training_data['tweet_text'][0]

if type(text) == str: # if value is str then encode to utf-8 byte string then decode back to str
    text = text.encode()
    text = text.decode()
elif type(text) == bytes: # elif value is bytes just decode to str
    text = text.decode()
else: # else printout to console if value is neither str or bytes
   print("Value not recognised as str or bytes!")
```